# Design pin diagram for custom board

Tags: diagram, component-diagram, app

I've a Vaman board similar to that in the image. I want to design pin diagram to this board. I'm not sure which software/apps were used and I'm looking for help in this.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you expect from the app? Would e.g. EAGLE/Fusion 360 work?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My aim to design a pinout diagram for an embedded board similar to that in the picture. I'm not sure which software/tool was used for this.

I'm not sure if EAGLE/Fusion 360 can do this job. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but by "exactly" I meant for you to provide more info - you should specify all the details, like system, whether it should be free or it can be paid, etc.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I want to make a pinout diagram like in the image, the tool should work in Ubuntu, preferably free.

Also, do you know which software is used to design the pinout diagrams in the embedded board manuals?

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind you need to edit the question with these details, instead of commenting.